# How to select data from model in Laravel 4 with a where clause

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have been trying to figure out how to do a simple select where on a table for a few hours now. I was trying to follow [this](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete) page but nothing I seem to try is working. Here is my model code with nothing in it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use BaseModel;

class Redemption extends BaseModel {


}
```

And here is the code I am trying to use in my controller.

```
$row = RedemptionModel::where('code', '=', Input::get('redemption_code'))->get();
var_dump($row);exit;
```

And here is the resulting data

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#162 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

I know that the db is working fine and the model is working fine because if I do `RedemptionModel::find(1)` that works. Also, if you know any good places to find ORM Laravel code with better examples please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` fetches a Collection object, which is essentially an array of items, even if there's only one result. In other words, your `$row` is actually row**s**.

If you want a single result, you can use `first()` instead of `get()`.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Why does Laravels examples suck so bad? They give absolute base functionality in a vacuum and I can not seem to find good documentation otherwise. Do you know a good place to look?

Comment: For instance what is wrong with this `$row = RedemptionModel::where('code', Input::get('redemption_code'))->pluck('b_redeemed')->first();`. I get an error, but it seems like that is the way to grab one column.

Comment: The documentation says `pluck()` gets a single column from a single row, so you don't need to call `first()` - `pluck` does that internally if necessary.